# Fitting a step function

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, best-fit-curve

I am trying to fit a step function using scipy.optimize.leastsq. Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

def fitfunc(p, x):
    y = np.zeros(x.shape)
    y[x < p[0]] = p[1]
    y[p[0] < x] = p[2]
    return y

errfunc = lambda p, x, y: fitfunc(p, x) - y # Distance to the target function

x = np.arange(1000)
y = np.random.random(1000)

y[x < 250.] -= 10

p0 = [500.,0.,0.]
p1, success = leastsq(errfunc, p0, args=(x, y))

print p1
```

the parameters are the location of the step and the level on either side. What's strange is that the first free parameter never varies, if you run that scipy will give

```
[  5.00000000e+02  -4.49410173e+00   4.88624449e-01]
```

when the first parameter would be optimal when set to 250 and the second to -10.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this might not be working and how to get it to work?

If I run

```
print np.sum(errfunc(p1, x, y)**2.)
print np.sum(errfunc([250.,-10.,0.], x, y)**2.)
```

I find:

```
12547.1054663
320.679545235
```

where the first number is what leastsq is finding, and the second is the value for the actual optimal function it should be finding.

Comment: You sure about the "would be optimal"? What's errfunc's value for the returned p1 and what is it for the `[250, whatever, -10]` you'd rather get?

Comment: added this info to the original post (rather than here, because the code gets messed up in the comment)

Comment: An alternative to curve fitting is to use wavelet techniques for feature extraction.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the fitting is much better if I add the epsfcn= argument to leastsq:

```
p1, success = leastsq(errfunc, p0, args=(x, y), epsfcn=10.)
```

and the result is

```
[ 248.00000146   -8.8273455     0.40818216]
```

My basic understanding is that the first free parameter has to be moved more than the spacing between neighboring points to affect the square of the residuals, and epsfcn has something to do with how big steps to use to find the gradient, or something similar.

Comment: This approach worked for me too; I recommend accepting it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that least squares fitting is the way to go about coming up with an approximation for a step.  I don't believe it will give you a satisfactory description of the discontinuity.  Least squares would not be my first thought when attacking this problem.

Why wouldn't you use a Fourier series approximation instead?  You'll always be stuck with Gibbs' phenomenon at the discontinuity, but the rest of the function can be approximated as well as you and your CPU can afford.

What exactly are you going to use this for?  Some context might help.

Comment: I have data the suffers from linear drift as a function of time. At some time t0, the drift suddenly jumps and has a different slope, and it happens a second time too. So what I really want to fit is three lines in three different ranges. The problem is, the jump times are not known in advance, and I need to do this for thousands of datasets, so I want the times of the jumps and the slopes and intercepts of the lines to be free parameters. I just thought I'd start with a simpler case.

Comment: If it's time-dependent data, all the more reason to use Fourier transforms.  Maybe an FFT would be more helpful.

Comment: SciPy has FFT capabilities: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft.html

Answer (score 1):

I propose approximating the step function. Instead of
inifinite slope at the "change point" make it linear over
one x distance (1.0 in the example). E.g. if the x
parameter, xp, for the function is defined as the midpoint
on this line then the value at xp-0.5 is the lower y value
and the value at xp+0.5 is the higher y value and
intermediate values of the function in the 
interval [xp-0.5; xp+0.5] is a linear
interpolation between these two points.

If it can be assumed that the step function (or its
approximation) goes from a lower value to a higher value
then I think the initial guess for the last two parameters
should be the lowest y value and the highest y value
respectively instead of 0.0 and 0.0.

---

I have 2 corrections:

1) np.random.random() returns random numbers in the range
0.0 to 1.0. Thus the mean is +0.5 and is also the value of
the third parameter (instead 0.0). And the second paramter
is then -9.5 (+0.5 - 10.0) instead of -10.0.

Thus

```
print np.sum(errfunc([250.,-10.,0.], x, y)**2.)
```

should be

```
print np.sum(errfunc([250.,-9.5,0.5], x, y)**2.)
```

2) In the original fitfunc() one value of y becomes 0.0 if x
is exactly equal to p[0]. Thus it is not a step function in
that case (more like a sum of two step functions). E.g. this
happens when the start value of the first parameter is 500.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your optimization is stuck in a *local minima*. I don't know what leastsq really works like, but if you give it an initial estimate of (0, 0, 0), it gets stuck there, too.

You can check the gradient at the initial estimate numerically (evaluate at +/- epsilon for a very small epsilon and divide bei 2*epsilon, take difference) and I bet it will be sth around 0.

Answer (score 0):

use statsmodel ols.  ols uses ordinary least square for curve fitting